# Inserting a value in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

My data is as follows,

```
data = [[2, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 1, 5], [1, 2, 2, 2], [2, 1, 2, 5], [2, 5, 2, 1]]
```

I would like to transform this such that there is a 0 at 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4th positions of the internal lists and get it look like below,

```
new_Data = [[0, 2, 1, 2, 2], [2, 0, 2, 1, 5], [1, 2, 0, 2, 2], [2, 1, 2, 0, 5], [2, 5, 2, 1, 0]]
```

I have tried using the following method,

```
a = 0

for n in range(len(mRco1)-1):

  mRco1[n][n] = [a]
```

But it does not seem to work.

Can anyone suggest how can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `list.insert()` method

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i].insert(i, 0)
```

result :

```
print(data)
>>> [[0, 2, 1, 2, 2], [2, 0, 2, 1, 5], [1, 2, 0, 2, 2], [2, 1, 2, 0, 5], [2, 5, 2, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd like to iterate over the lists in `data`, and for the n'th list, insert a `0` at position `n`. You can use the `insert` function for that, and define the following loop:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i].insert(i, 0)
```